# angular mat-menu not showing using matMenuTriggerFor

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a simple menu to show when clicking on a button, but I'm not able to get `matMenuTriggerFor` to work. You can see the whole project at https://github.com/yperess/risc16 (it's basically just a stub).

The main issue is the toolbar component:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="fileMenu">File</button>
<mat-menu #fileMenu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Hello</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Here, clicking on the File button doesn't open the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the 'File' button you get the following error in the console:

> ERROR Error: Found the synthetic listener @transformMenu.start. Please
> include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in
> your application.

Simply add one of these modules to your imports and your menu will work correctly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-xtpwhw?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this suggestion fixed the problem for me even though I wasn't getting any errors in the console! Thanks for that, I spent a couple of hours trying to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

please import above animation package in `app.module.ts` file , it will work nicely

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by using `ViewChild` and `MatMenuTrigger` at the same time.

imports are

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material/menu';
```

within the export class, you can use it like

```
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;
```

or individually

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="belowMenu" 
  #clickHoverMenuTrigger="matMenuTrigger">
  <mat-icon class="icon-color">insert_link</mat-icon>
  Share
</button>

@ViewChild('clickHoverMenuTrigger') trigger: MatMenuTrigger;
```

Now just call it within your function

```
myFunc(){
  this.trigger.openMenu(); //for opening the menu
  this.trigger.closeMenu(); //for closing the menu
}
```

for more details check [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-open-menu-programmatically?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).